# AEM - Custom workflow with Author content validation ?

Tags: workflow, aem, author

How to write AEM - Custom workflow with Author content validation ?

eg: I want to validate Author HTML content while doing page activation. 
I want to check all Hyperlinks in Author content, based on specific link fail the workflow or pass the workflow for activation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AEM Workflow documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/extending/workflows/wf-extending.html#Developing%20Process%20Step%20Implementations) is very helpful on this subject. You will need to create service that implements the `WorkflowProcess` interface. Once that is done, you can create a new workflow at http://localhost:4502/workflow or you can update the default activation workflow at http://localhost:4502/cf#/etc/workflow/models/request_for_activation.html. Drop in a new `Process Step`, set the `Advance Handler` to true and the `Process` to your service. Don't forget to hit the `Save` button.

In your service, you have access to the Session and thus the Resource Resolver as well as the path to the activated resource. That's all you need to get the resource and run your custom code against its properties. If your custom validation comes back false, you can terminate the workflow by using `wfsession.terminateWorkflow(item.getWorkflow())`, otherwise the workflow will continue because you set it to auto advance.

This is a rough outline for your workflow process step:

```
@Component
@Service
@Properties({
    @Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION, value = "Workflow step description"),
    @Property(name = Constants.SERVICE_VENDOR, value = "Company Name"),
    @Property(name = "process.label", value = "Process Label will show in the workflow dropdown") })
public class MyCustomStep implements WorkflowProcess {

    public void execute(WorkItem item, WorkflowSession wfsession, MetaDataMap args) throws WorkflowException {
        ResourceResolver resolver = wfsession.adaptTo(ResourceResolver.class);

        if (resolver != null) {
            // Get the payload: the activated resource
            String path = item.getWorkflowData().getPayload().toString();

            Resource resource = resolver.getResource(path);

            if (resource != null) {
                ValueMap properties = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
                String propertyToCheck = properties.get("myPropertyName", String.class);

                if (!customValidationMethod(propertyToCheck)) {
                    // Terminate workflow
                    wfsession.terminateWorkflow(item.getWorkflow());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks nateyolles for nice explanation.

Comment: Thanks nateyolles for nice explanation.  Please ignore my silly question, i am new to AEM.  How can i debug service code in local?

Comment: This article gives step by step instructions: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/CQ5HowToSetupRemoteDebuggingWithEclipse.html. If you have further questions, it would be better to start a new Question on StackOverflow as this conversation doesn't pertain to the original question.

Comment: My pleasure. If you found the answer that you need, please remember to upvote and mark an answer as correct.